# How can I update an HWND's style and position atomically?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm writing a Win7 desktop app and want to have it seamlessly transition from windowed to windowed-fullscreen (and vice-versa), and have mostly accomplished this by calling [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to update its style immediately followed by [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to update its size and position.  The problem is that the window flashes for one frame to show its style updated, but the new size and position are not shown.  The next frame everything looks correct but I'm trying to avoid this single-frame artifact.

I've tried reversing the order in which I call the APIs but it just changes what the artifact looks like.  I've also tried hiding the window, calling the APIs, and then showing the window, but this just causes the window to disappear for the one frame.

I know that one option is to create a new window with the desired properties then destroy the old one, but I wanted to find a less expensive alternative.

So is there any way to call these APIs and have them be visually reflected atomically?  As a bonus, it'd be nice to also have the multiple resulting WM_SIZE messages coalesced into a single event, but I can manage that myself in the message handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this sort of thing reliably is difficult in Windows, particularly since Vista as the DWM can complicate things. It's often a matter of trial and error until you find a solution that works for you.

`SetWindowPos` has an `SWP_NOREDRAW` flag that prevents the window from being redrawn in response to the call. So you could try changing the position first, then updating the styles, and finally a third call to redraw the window in its new location. For example,

```
SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, x, y, w, h, SWP_NOREDRAW | SWP_NOZORDER);
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, dwNewStyles);
RedrawWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_FRAME);
```

Comment: Most accurate answer, though I couldn't get anything that was consistently artifact-free on multiple machines, including using the RedrawWindow approach.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> Certain window data is cached, so changes you make using
>   [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will not take effect until you call the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
>   function.

So this *should* work.  Perhaps try using SetWindowPos instead of MoveWindow.

Are you doing anything interesting in your window proc when you get the events that are caused by these calls?  In particular, are you "fixing" the size or anything like that?

Comment: I've tried SetWindowPos as well, and it produces the same results.  The only thing I'm doing in my wndproc is handling WM_SYSCHAR for the Alt+Enter command.  I do "fix" the size but only if it's less than 128 pixels, so it's not hit in this case (verified with debugger).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`WM_SETREDRAW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); use it to disable redraw, change the window styles, and then call `RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_FRAME | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ALLCHILDREN)` to display them atomically.

Comment: The window may ignore this message

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "windowed-fullscreen"?  Is it the same as maximized?

If so, [`ShowWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)`(hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE)` ?

Comment: No, I mean WS_POPUP style with the client rect equal to the monitor rect.  Also referred to as [Borderless Fullscreen](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderless_fullscreen_windowed), this causes some efficiency wins when using DirectX.  It looks like SW_MAXIMIZE does work as an alternative to MoveWindow, but it doesn't eliminate the artifact since I still need to adjust the window style first.