# Going Fullscreen in win32 without 2 WM_SIZE message

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, fullscreen, directx-12

So I am creating a fullscreen function in win32 c++ doing:

```cpp
uint8_t isFullscreen = 0;

RECT winRect;           //Current Window Rect
RECT nonFullScreenRect; //Rect Not In Full Screen Position (used to restore window to not full screen position when coming out of fullscreen) 

uint32_t screen_width = DEFAULT_SCREEN_WIDTH;
uint32_t screen_height = DEFAULT_SCREEN_HEIGHT;

void Fullscreen( HWND WindowHandle )
{
    isFullscreen = isFullscreen ^ 1;
    if( isFullscreen )
    {
        //saving off current window rect
        nonFullScreenRect.left = winRect.left;
        nonFullScreenRect.right = winRect.right;
        nonFullScreenRect.bottom = winRect.bottom;
        nonFullScreenRect.top = winRect.top;
        SetWindowLongPtr( WindowHandle, GWL_STYLE,  WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE );  //causes a resize msg 
        HMONITOR hmon = MonitorFromWindow(WindowHandle, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
        MONITORINFO mi = { sizeof( mi ) };
        GetMonitorInfo( hmon, &mi );
        screen_width = mi.rcMonitor.right - mi.rcMonitor.left;
        screen_height = mi.rcMonitor.bottom - mi.rcMonitor.top;
        MoveWindow( WindowHandle, mi.rcMonitor.left, mi.rcMonitor.top, (int32_t)screen_width, (int32_t)screen_height, FALSE );      
    }
    else
    {
        SetWindowLongPtr( WindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE );
        screen_width = nonFullScreenRect.right - nonFullScreenRect.left;
        screen_height = nonFullScreenRect.bottom - nonFullScreenRect.top;
        MoveWindow( WindowHandle, nonFullScreenRect.left, nonFullScreenRect.top, (int32_t)screen_width, (int32_t)screen_height, FALSE );
    }
}
```

However when it goes fullscreen, the function generates 2 WM_SIZE messages. While when it goes windowed, it generates only 1.

Why is that the case? And how can I make it generate only 1 WM_SIZE message for the proper full screen size?

[How can I update an HWND's style and position atomically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036144/how-can-i-update-an-hwnds-style-and-position-atomically) asks about it but no one answers it

The reasons I need this is because I am using DirectX12 and on WM_SIZE I wait for all the signals at the end of the command queues before resizing all the swap chain back buffers. And I don't want to have to resize the swap chain twice when switching to fullscreen mode.

```cpp
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        screen_width = LOWORD( LParam );
        screen_height = HIWORD( LParam );
        //DirectX stuff here
    }break;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `isFullscreen = isFullscreen ^ 1;` - only a game developer would write code like this. :)  Aside from that, what problem can't be solved by detecting that your second WM_SIZE is the same width/height as the previous one?  Or are you getting two WM_SIZE messages of different params in each?

Comment: @selbie but it isn't the same height and width as the previous one.  its almost like in one case SetWindowLongPtr is causing a WM_SIZE. But it isn't in both cases. But I don't know if SetWindowLongPtr  is actually generating a message

Comment: I put a print statement in WM_SIZE
 When going windowed: `Old: 1280 720 New: 1264 681`.    When Going fullscreen
`Old: 1264 681 New: 1280 720`
 `Old: 1920 1080 New: 1920 1080` Note that the fullscreen func is also setting the screen_width and screen_height globals

Comment: You seem to be ignoring part of the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw): *"Certain window data is cached, so changes you make using `SetWindowLongPtr` will not take effect until you call the [`SetWindowPos`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) function."* I believe the window border is part of the *"certain window data"*. Try replacing your `MoveWindow` call with a call to `SetWindowPos`. I don't know whether this solves your immediate issue but it is something you need to fix.

Comment: @IInspectable when i swapped to SetWindowPos, it no longer let me Alt-Tab out of the program (maybe i have to handle that manually?). Also still calls it twice. I will have to do some more investigating. Maybe something else in my program is generating 2 messages.

Comment: `SetWindowPos` is a complex API. Since we don't know how you're calling it, we cannot know whether the call is correct or not. At any rate, it seems that you're manually replicating what [DXGI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi) is doing for you already (at least as I understand it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated Answer:

The Win32 API allows you to modify parameters of the window one at a time. When a parameter is modified, the API may or may not update the window and trigger a WM_SIZE that will be the size of the window given the current parameters.

Since to have a complete full screen window you need to make at least 2 calls, one to update GWL_STYLE and another to update GWL_EXSTYLE, you have a big chance of getting 2 WM_SIZE calls. One of them will give you the window size without the menu, and the other the full screen window size. It depends in which order you call `SetWindowLongPtr`, but you'll probably get 2 WM_SIZE and only the second one is "correct", i.e. the one you want in the end.

The more reliable solution to your problem is to use a variable at the top of Main.cpp:

`int isTogglingFullScreen = false;`

Then inside your full screen toggle code (note where `isTogglingFullScreen`  is being set):

```
   case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_RETURN && (lParam & 0x60000000) == 0x20000000)
        {
            // Implements the classic ALT+ENTER fullscreen toggle
            if (s_fullscreen)
            {
                isTogglingFullScreen = true;
                SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
                isTogglingFullScreen = false;
                SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, 0);

                int width = 800;
                int height = 600;
                if (game)
                    game->GetDefaultSize(width, height);

                SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);


                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

            }
            else
            {
                isTogglingFullScreen = true;
                SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TOPMOST);
                SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP);
                SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

                isTogglingFullScreen = false;

                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
            }

            s_fullscreen = !s_fullscreen;
        }
        break;
```

Finally, inside WM_SIZE, change

```
        else if (!s_in_sizemove && game)
        {
            game->OnWindowSizeChanged(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
        }
```

to

```
        else if (!s_in_sizemove && game && !isTogglingFullScreen)
        {
            game->OnWindowSizeChanged(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
        }
```

This will give you a single call to `OnWindowSizeChanged()` when you toggle full screen, and the call will be with the correct final size.

--

Old Answer:

If you only want a single WM_SIZE to trigger, when you switch to full screen then you should go for something like this:

```
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TOPMOST);
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

**Any `SetWindowLongPtr` call to GWL_STYLE** will trigger a WM_SIZE, so make sure it's only called with `GWL_EXSTYLE`. For example, if you both set `GWL_EXSTYLE` to what you want, and reset `GWL_STYLE` to 0, you'll trigger WM_SIZE twice.

To make it clearer:

- Don't use GWL_STYLE in SetWindowLongPtr because it triggers a useless WM_SIZE
- ShowWindow will trigger WM_SIZE
- The above code will ultimately only trigger WM_SIZE once.

It turns out that YMMV. It's entirely possible that the first time you switch fullscreen, you'll get 2 WM_SIZE. One will be with the original size, and the other with the new size. Subsequent calls will trigger only one WM_SIZE.

Hence, the really bulletproof solution (which I was using anyway before playing around with the `SetWindowLongPtr` to answer this question, is to validate that the window size has actually changed. Because one thing that I can guarantee in the above call is that you'll never get more than 1 call with the new size. At most you'll get a WM_SIZE call with the old size, which you'll discard by checking that it's the same as the current size.

If you use the DevicesResources template for DX12, you'll see that there's a check in `OnWindowSizeChanged()` that does nothing if the size hasn't changed.

Comment: How does this help in removing any non-client areas from a window? Clearly, when going "full screen" you'll want to remove the border and caption bar from the window. Otherwise you'll wind up with a window whose client area either doesn't fill the entire display area, or have the non-client areas extend into adjacent monitors. This reads like an answer that solves a problem that does not match the problem stated in the question.

Comment: There are many ways to go full screen. One of the ways is this, which is full screen but with the menu bar left on the screen.
The question was how to avoid multiple WM_SIZE calls, not which full screen style one wants.

Comment: Conflating "full screen" and "maximized window" will not turn this into an answer to the question.

Comment: Fair. I'll update my answer with a solution that answers the question a different way.